# ag-grid version upgrade issue: count not find matching row model for rowModelType virtual

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I upgraded my ag-grid version from v7.0.2 to v11.0.0.
After this upgraded suddenly all the tables having infinite scrolling started failing.
I get this error on my browser console:

> ag-Grid: count not find matching row model for rowModelType virtual

I checked there changelog here https://www.ag-grid.com/change-log/changeLogIndex.php#gsc.tab=0

But I could not find anything related to this. So I believe this is not been removed.

Also I tried to change rowModelType to **'infinite'**. Changing this, I was able to see some data on my UI, though it was not behaving as expected (Rows were fluctutating)

Can any one please help me here to point out the equivalent class I can use if rowModalType: **'virtual'** is depracaded.

My ag-grid option:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    headerHeight: 25,
    rowHeight: constants.height,
    rowModelType: 'virtual',
    paginationPageSize: constants.ag_grid_page_size,
    virtualPaging: true,
    enableServerSideSorting: true,
    enableSorting: false,
    enableColResize: true,
    angularCompileRows: true,
    onGridSizeChanged: function () {
        $scope.gridOptions.api.doLayout();
        $scope.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    },
    columnDefs: [..]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual row model was renamed to infinite. It was a name change, the row model is the same one. You did jump a lot of versions, so there must be another breaking change. I cannot say what's wrong from the code you posted, I suggest you look at the examples online for the version you want and compare what you have to a working example.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version (17.1.1) you can use `pagination:true`

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs,
    rowData: $scope.rowData,
    rowHeight: 48,
    components: {
        childMessageRenderer: $scope.childMessageRenderer
    },
    angularCompileRows: true,
    enableFilter: true,
    pagination: true,
    paginationPageSize :3
};
```